# How can you add more than one captions language?

Tags: vtt

I have created a logic app, to pull the Video Transcript(VTT) files, once the videos have been indexed. I wanted the user to have the ability to choose which language caption they want from a list of options(E.g English, Spanish, French etc). Is there a way to add group of checkboxes for each of the languages for the user to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the language as the http request query parameter the set it in the code view mode.

Set the language value with `@triggerOutputs()['queries']['language']`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I mean is there a checkbox in the logic app for each of the languages for the user to choose?

Comment: No such component for this connector.

Comment: And i don't think you need checkbox, cause the api only support one language.https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the Http request URL will be like? Like the format? Your screen shot is cutting things of.

Comment: I just use the url logic app provide with a query parameter `language`.`https://logic host.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/flowid/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=sig value&language=German`

Comment: Any update now? If this could help you,  you could accept it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, we are looking for way to add 8 different languages as an option for the user to pick. We want to create a checkbox with translation options. Could you please help, how can do with logic app?

Comment: any idea how I can proceed on this?

Comment: You just want to provide 8 languages as a choice, so in my answer I choose to pass the language as a query parameter, I suppose this is what I could provide.

Comment: so how can I provide 8 languages as a choice for the user to choose? How can I implement that?

Comment: Where do you want to use the logic app http url ? In web or other scenario？

Comment: Perhaps you could consider this some constructive feedback - people are not going to be inclined to assist if you never close off questions and instead just ask new things on comments and additional questions. I know you possible feel your actual root problem is not solved, but it's your job to parcel that problem up into reasonably scoped questions and acknowledge when those questions have been answered

Comment: @Peter, if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. If you want to ask other question you should post a new question, only change the question tag and content won't help you to get  other answers.

Comment: @GeorgeChen It some what helps, I will accept it as answer. Thanks for your feedback.